# Solving $[x^2]+2[x]=3x$, where [.] dnotes GIF/Floor function

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

For solving $$[x^2]+2[x]=3x,....(1)$$ where [.] denotes GIF/Floor  function, we use the estimation rule that $F-1<[F] \le F$. We write $x^2-1 < [x^2] \le x^2$  and $2(x-1) < 2[x] \le 2x$. Adding them we get $$ x^2+2x-3 < 3x \le x^2+2x \implies x^2-x-3<0 ~\&~ x(x-1) \ge 0.$$  These two inequations yield $x\in \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}, 0\right]\cup \left[1, \frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)\implies x \in (-1.3027,0] \cup  [1,2.3027).$
From  (1), we have  $3x \in I \implies (i): x \in I, (ii): x \notin I.$

Case (i): the possibilities are $x=-1,0,1,2$, wherein only $x=0,1$ satisfy (1).

Case (ii): The posibilities are $x=-1/3,-2/3, 4/3, 5/3$, but out of these only $-2/3$ satisfies Eq. (1).

Finally, Eq.(1) has three roots $-2/3,0,1$. However, if plot $f(x)=[x^2]+2[x]-3x$, there appears to be a root in the left vicinity of $-1$, see below

[image]

The question is what is this root numerically? What could be other methods of finding all roots of Eq. (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plot is missing some discrete points. For example, $f(-1)=2$ and this is not represented in your graph. What you see at $-1$ is just $\lim_{x\to-1^{-}}f(x)=0$. Because for a small $\varepsilon>0$, $f(-1-\varepsilon)=1+2(-2)-3(-1-\varepsilon)=3\varepsilon$.

For definitively identifying all roots of $f$, note that $3x$ must be an integer. So any root has to be of the form $\frac{m}{3}$ where $m$ is an integer. There are only finitely many such numbers to check in, say $[-1.3027,2.3027]$.

Comment: I appreciate your first point. I would like to add that $f(-1+h)=1-h,h>0$ (discontinuity at $x=-1$) is depicted in the figure. Please see my discussion roots will be found in $(-1.3027,0] \cup  [1,2.3027).$ and these are $-2/3,0,1$. The question is whether these are all the roots or not. Please, comment on this,

Comment: My second paragraph explains why $-2/3$, $0$, and $1$ are the only roots.

Comment: @ZAhmed $f(-1+h)=1-h,h>0$ tells us that $\lim_{x\to-1^+}f(x)=1.$ That tells us what is on the right side of the line $x=-1$ in the graph, as does the diagonal line segment that appears to end at $(-1,1)$ in your graph. Near that point, the graph is near $y=1,$ hence not containing a root. Likewise the diagonal segment that appears to end at $(-1,0)$ on your graph tells us what happens on the left side of the line $x=-1.$ On the left side of that line the graph is positive, hence it has no root there. But neither segment says what happens *exactly* at $x=-1.$

Comment: @ZAhmed The weakness of this way of graphing the function is that it does not show what happens at each end point of each line segment. Sometimes the endpoint is part of the function definition and sometimes it is not. In this case, the endpoint that appears to be a "root" at $(-1,0)$ is actually not part of the function. The segment does get arbitrarily close to the $x$ axis, but "close" does not count for roots.

Comment: @David K Can $x=-1$ be called limit point of $f(x)$?

Comment: A limit point of a function lives in the codomain, at least by any meaning of that phrase I am familiar with. So it is not an $x$-value.